# Solution file is not there after get latest from Microsoft team foundation server 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I had a project running on my local machine which is connected to Team foundation server. But one day I click on get latest from server and it override my files and in my project folder solution file is lost.So  now I can't open the project.So how can I get back my solution file?

Comment: Have you ever deleted the solution file before? Please check if the solution file existing in remote TFS.

Comment: No.but after i get the latest version from TFS i got one solution metadata file in replace of solution file.

Comment: Whatever, please have a try with the ways mentioned in below answer to check if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks it helps.I cant voted you as i don't have the rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, the solution file should be deleted from remote repository in TFS with the latest changeset.

To get back the solution file, you can check the changesets to find the last changeset which has the solution file, then **get specific version** from this changeset. You can also try to **Rollback** to the specific version.

1. Right click on the branch or project folder that includes the
   solution file
2. Select **Advanced** > **Get Specific Version ...**
3. On Get dialog set Type to **Changeset**
4. Set Changset to a specific changset number which has the solution file
5. Click **Get**
6. Check in the new changes

***Note*** : Backup current local changes if needed

[image]